# How to add separate project and initialization of the class library

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin forms and one provider that offer some solution and extra setting for that sikutuion. I would like to add that setting in completely separated project so if I use different provider it won't be an issue. So I have added Class Library and started implementing the solution. However now I am a bit unsure on how to approach this.

I have added and reference and now just testing the connection I get system null reference.

My xaml where I am just now trying to display a string from the class library

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
                      <Grid Grid.Row ="1" RowSpacing="0" >
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding TestString}"  HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" />                
                </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>

Back of my page

  public partial class TestService : ContentPage
  {
    private readonly Regula.CustomSettings res;

    public TestService(Regula.CustomSettings res)
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      res = new Regula.CustomSettings();
      BindingContext = new Test(res);
    }
   
  }
```

ViewModel

```
public class Test : BaseViewModel
  {
    private Regula.CustomSettings res;

    public Test(Regula.CustomSettings res)
    {
      res = new Regula.CustomSettings();
    }

    public string TestString
    {
      get => res.TestString;
      set
      {
        res.TestString = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TestString");
      }
    }
  }
```

And the Library

```
public class CustomSettings
{
  public string TestString = "test";

  public CustomSettings()
  {
    TestString = "Test";
  }
}
```

Please can you advise how to get my string from the library? Or how to google this stuff?

Comment: why are you passing `CustomSettings` as an argument to the constructor and then setting it to a new instance?  This doesn't make any sense, and you are doing it in both constructors,.

Comment: can you please show me the correct way

Comment: `this.res = res;`

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the **CustomSettings** as follows:

```
public class CustomSettings
{
    public string TestString { set; get; }
}
```

And then modify **Test** ViewModel as follows:

```
public class Test: BaseViewModel
{
    public CustomSettings customSettings { set; get; }
    public Test(CustomSettings cusSettings)
    {
        this.customSettings = cusSettings;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return customSettings.TestString; }
        set
        {
            if (customSettings.TestString == value)
                return;
            customSettings.TestString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in **TestService** contentpage:

```
public partial class TestService : ContentPage
{

  public TestService(Regula.CustomSettings res)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    CustomSettings customSettings = new CustomSettings() { TestString = "TestData" };
    Test testModel = new Test(customSettings);
    this.BindingContext = testModel;
  }

}
```

The effect:

[image]

Note: If want to use **MVVM** with `ListView`, you could refer to [this official sample](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/TodoMvvm/TodoMvvm/ViewModels).

Comment: sorry, is that custom settings a class library outside of the project? This is shared project, iOS, android and the another project custom settings

Comment: just based on the sample you sent I don't think it answered the question.

Comment: @VanessaKensington Okey, could you share the code of using the shared project or a sample project link? I will check that and then can modify my answer.

Comment: will do, I upload it and let ou know

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7iuybc2s9m0v7al/AABN6Rc3U66O90307jZ2b7yGa?dl=0

Comment: @VanessaKensington Hi, the shared link is not a complete sample project. And from broswing the code, can not find the shared library project, only a `CustomSettings.cs` file. Abour [the reference of PCL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=macos) , you could have a look at [this sample project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/mobile-samples/taskyportable/).